# spark sql datediff in days

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate the number of days between current_timestamp() and max(timestamp_field) from a table.

```
maxModifiedDate = spark.sql("select date_format(max(lastmodifieddate), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss') as maxModifiedDate,date_format(current_timestamp(),'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss') as CurrentTimeStamp, datediff(current_timestamp(), date_format(max(lastmodifieddate), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')) as daysDiff from db.tbl")
```

but I get null for daysDiff. Why is that and how can I fix it?

```
------------------+-------------------+--------+
|    maxModifiedDate|   CurrentTimeStamp|daysDiff|
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
|01/29/2020 05:07:51|06/29/2020 08:36:28|    null|
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out: I used `to_timestamp` to convert into dateformat and used `datediff` function to calculate the time difference.

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    # InputDF
    # +-------------------+-------------------+
    # |    maxModifiedDate|   CurrentTimeStamp|
    # +-------------------+-------------------+
    # |01/29/2020 05:07:51|06/29/2020 08:36:28|
    # +-------------------+-------------------+


    df.select("maxModifiedDate","CurrentTimeStamp",F.datediff( F.to_timestamp("CurrentTimeStamp", format= 'MM/dd/yyyy'), F.to_timestamp("maxModifiedDate", format= 'MM/dd/yyyy')).alias("datediff")).show()


    # +-------------------+-------------------+--------+
    # |    maxModifiedDate|   CurrentTimeStamp|datediff|
    # +-------------------+-------------------+--------+
    # |01/29/2020 05:07:51|06/29/2020 08:36:28|    152|
    # +-------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Using `sparksql`

```
spark.sql("select maxModifiedDate,CurrentTimeStamp, datediff(to_timestamp(CurrentTimeStamp,  'MM/dd/yyyy'), to_timestamp(maxModifiedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')) as datediff from table ").show()
```

Comment: maxModifiedDate = spark.sql('select date_format(max(lastmodifieddate),"yyyy-MM-dd 'T'HH:mm:ssXXX") as ddDate from db.table')

I keep getting errors but apparently this is a standard format to use. I need the date return to be like this: 2020-06-17T15:08:24Z

I can't seem to get that T in there...

Answer (score 1):

[`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/sql/#date_format) is used to change timestamp formats instead use **`to_date(col,'fmt'), unix_timestamp+from_unixtime,to_timestamp`** functions with **`datediff`**.

```
df.show()
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|    maxModifiedDate|   CurrentTimeStamp|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|01/29/2020 05:07:51|06/29/2020 08:36:28|
#+-------------------+-------------------+

spark.sql("select maxModifiedDate,CurrentTimeStamp,datediff(to_date(maxModifiedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy'),to_date(CurrentTimeStamp,'MM/dd/yyyy')) as daysDiff from tmp").show()
#+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
#|    maxModifiedDate|   CurrentTimeStamp|daysDiff|
#+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
#|01/29/2020 05:07:51|06/29/2020 08:36:28|    -152|
#+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try to define your own function to solve your problem, since `datediff()` is only able to compute difference between dates and not datetimes.

I suggest you something like this, casting your datetime to long:

```
diff_datetime = col("end_time").cast("long") - col("start_time").cast("long")
df = df.withColumn("diff", diff/60)
```

Or casting your result to timestamp using SQL

```
SELECT datediff(F.to_timestamp(end_date), F.to_timestamp(start_date))
```

In this case, I'm going to get the difference in seconds between two datetimes, but you can edit this result changing the scale factor (60 for seconds, 60*60 for minutes...)

Alternatively, if you want to use that function, you have to cast your datetime column to a date column (without hours, minutes and seconds) using `to_date()` and then apply `datediff()`.